# "But anything to..."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I'm wondering about the grammaticality of a sentence like "That might have been a far-fetched argument. **But anything to make my point**." (I'm curious specifically about the sentence in bold.)

Although the sentence seems technically to be a fragment, I wonder if it could be considered acceptable (even in an academic paper), or if it would have to be somehow re-written/re-worded.

My argument that it's correct is that there would be an ellipsed "I would do" in the sentence, as in "But [I would do] anything to...", which I would think is allowed. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that there is an elliptical **I would do** in the sense in which *elliptical* is normally used.

Generally, elliptical constructions are more explicit:

> I ate chicken and then [I ate] dessert.

Here, *I ate* is already used in the first part of the sentence, so it's omitted presence is easily assumed in the second part of the sentence.

Or:

> Did you have chicken for dinner?
>   Yes [, I had chicken for dinner].

Answering *yes* or *no* is commonplace, and the omitted information from the question is easily assumed.

> That might have been a far-fetched argument. But anything to make my point.

You *might* look at your construction as an example of an elliptical sentence. But I think it would be putting too much of a burden on the reader. There is no *obvious* context from which **I would do** can be taken as the missing phrase.

You have struggle briefly to come up with omitted words that make the second sentence complete. In fact, first I try to change the punctuation. Then I consider what else would make it work. It took me about ten seconds to come up with **I would do** as a possibility.

Any construction that causes a reader to pause or backtrack in order to parse it should probably be rephrased.

In this case, it seems fairly trivial to add that missing **I would do**—so, why wouldn't you?